# python Json conversion issue

Tags: python, json, type-conversion

```
                    if not server in finalOp.keys():
                            #pdb.set_trace()
                            finalOp[server] = []
                            req = Request('http://localhost:80/status.json')
                            res = urlopen(req)
                            jsonCont = json.loads(str(res.read().decode()))  
                            for key, val in jsonCont.items():
                                  if type(val) is list:
                                          val = ''.join(val)
                                  content.append(key+''+val)
                            #format {'server': [{content}]
                            finalOp[server].append('{'+','.join(content)+'}')

            except URLError as e:
                    #Assgining NA when URL not reachable or request not fulfilled
                    content = ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
                    finalOp[server].append('{'+','.join(content)+'}')
```

**here is the error:**

> for key, val in jsonCont.items():          AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the json so we can see what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Here is the json file                                                                                                                                       [{
 "Application": "WebApp01",
 "Version": "1.0.1",
 "Uptime": "{{integer(1000, 100000)}}",
 "Request_Count": "{{integer(1000, 100000 * 5)}}",
 "Error_Count": "{{integer(1000, 4000 * 2)}}",
 "Success_Count": "{{integer(1000, 80000 * 2)}}"
}]

Answer (score 1):

What is the format of the JSON? When you do  json.loads(), if it reads it as a list, the ".items()" method will not work.

```
json.loads('[{"name": "John", "age": 31, "city": "New York"}]').items()
```

vs

```
json.loads('{"name": "John", "age": 31, "city": "New York"}').items()
```

I imagine you are receiving the first example. You may need to do a little validating/cleaning to make sure it's in the structure you are expecting.